# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'update_datalim'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a candlestick graph using some data that I have stored in a CSV file and the `mpl_finance` library:

The first five rows look like this:

```
              Date               Open      High       Low     Close    Volume

0  2017-08-24 04:00:00.000000  0.002890  0.002890  0.002670  0.002670  371.64
1  2017-08-24 04:05:00.000000  0.002669  0.002669  0.002669  0.002669    4.80
2  2017-08-24 04:10:00.000000  0.002600  0.002649  0.002600  0.002649   61.71
3  2017-08-24 04:15:00.000000  0.002640  0.002640  0.002640  0.002640   20.00
4  2017-08-24 04:20:00.000000  0.002620  0.002620  0.002600  0.002602   92.68
```

Below is the **code** I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ochl

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

candlestick2_ochl(ax = df["Date"],opens=df["Open"],closes=df["Close"],highs =df["High"],lows = df["Low"])
plt.show()
```

When I run this code I get the following **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 5.py", line 16, in <module>
    candlestick2_ochl(ax = df["Date"],opens=df["Open"],closes=df["Close"],highs =df["High"],lows = df["Low"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_finance.py", line 552, in candlestick2_ochl
    alpha=alpha)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_finance.py", line 633, in candlestick2_ohlc
    ax.update_datalim(corners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'update_datalim'
```

*(PS: I've tried running the code without `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])` but it output the same error)*

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You will want to use `candlestick_ochl` instead of `candlestick2_ochl` to be able to have the dates on the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for your comment! And how do I add the dates to candlestick_ochl?

Comment: Check maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380298/4124317)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [documentation of  candlestick2_ochl](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html):

> ```
> matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes,
> width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)
> ```
>
> Represent the open,
>       close as a bar line and high low range as a vertical line.
>
> NOTE: this code assumes if any value open, low, high, close is missing
>   they all are missing
>
> Parameters:    ax : Axes
>
> an Axes instance to plot to
>
> [...]

So, `ax` specifies, which plot/subplot your graph will end up on.

in your code, data is assigned to this variable. So, you should create you own ax, and feed that to the function, like so:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

candlestick2_ochl(ax=ax, opens=df["Open"],closes=df["Close"],highs =df["High"],lows = df["Low"])
```

as for the question with `plt.subplot(1,1,1):`
This means 1x1 grid, first location. You can go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111) post for more information on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm able to plot the graph now but sadly x-axis isn't labeled using `df["Date"]`, do you have an idea on how this could be fixed?

Comment: also what do the `1`'s in `fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)` mean?

Comment: could you try df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

Comment: I've just added this to the code but it doesn't change anything

Comment: what happens when you do print(df.index) ?

Comment: it gives me something like this `Index(['2017-08-27 15:20:00.000000',...]` (it contains all of the dates)